# Javascript How to get Nested Objects Correctly

Tags: javascript, json, object, electron, typeerror

I am building an Electron app that gets a certain kind of json file from the user and logs all the data from it. But I am getting an error about getting undefined from the quantity:
Json File:

```json
{
  "tiers": [
    {
      "trades": [
        {
          "wants": [
            {
              "item": "minecraft:string",
              "quantity": {
                "min": 15,
                "max": 20
              }
            }
          ],
          "gives": [
            {
              "item": "minecraft:emerald"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "wants": [
            {
              "item": "minecraft:emerald"
            }
          ],
          "gives": [
            {
              "item": "minecraft:arrow",
              "quantity": {
                "min": 8,
                "max": 12
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "trades": [
        {
          "wants": [
            {
              "item": "minecraft:gravel",
              "quantity": 10
            },
            {
              "item": "minecraft:emerald",
              "quantity": 1
            }
          ],
          "gives": [
            {
              "item": "minecraft:flint",
              "quantity": {
                  "min": 6,
                  "max": 10
                }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "wants": [
            {
              "item": "minecraft:emerald",
              "quantity": {
                "min": 2,
                "max": 3
              }
            }
          ],
          "gives": [
            {
              "item": "minecraft:bow"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is the main.js:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, dialog, ipcRenderer, globalShortcut } = require('electron');
const { autoUpdater } = require('electron-updater');
const path = require('path');
const Store = require('./classes/Store.js');
const { electron } = require('process');
const { setTimeout } = require('timers');

// import Vue from 'vue';
// import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
// import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";

// Vue.use(Vuetify);

let win;
let loadingScreen;

const store = new Store({
    configName: 'settings',
    defaults: {
        windowBounds: {
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
        },
        isMaximized: false,
        fullscreen: false
    }
});

function createLoadingScreen() {
    loadingScreen = new BrowserWindow(Object.assign({
        width: 200,
        height: 220,
        frame: false,
        transparent: true,
        icon: 'build/icons/icon.png',
        webPreferences: {
            worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true
        }
    }));
    loadingScreen.setResizable(false);
    loadingScreen.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/extraWindows/loadingScreen/loading.html');
    loadingScreen.setOverlayIcon('build/icons/icon.png', "Route");
    loadingScreen.on('closed', () => loadingScreen = null);
    loadingScreen.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
        loadingScreen.show();
    });
}

function createWindow() {
    let width = store.get('windowBounds.width');
    let height = store.get('windowBounds.height');
    let x = store.get('windowBounds.x');
    let y = store.get('windowBounds.y');
    let isMaximized = store.get('isMaximized');

    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width,
        height,
        x,
        y,
        icon: 'build/icons/icon.png',
        frame: false,
        titleBarStyle: "hidden",
        webPreferences: {
            enableRemoteModule: true,
            nodeIntegration: true,
            webSafeExecuteJavaScript: true
        },
        show: false
    })

    win.setOverlayIcon('build/icons/icon.png', "Route");

    if(isMaximized == true) {
        win.maximize();
    }

    win.loadFile('index.html');

    win.on('closed', function() {
        win = null;
        settingScreen = null;
    });
    win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
        if(loadingScreen) {
            loadingScreen.close();
            win.show();
        }
    })

    win.on('resize', () => {
        store.set('windowBounds', win.getBounds());
    });
    win.on('move', () => {
        store.set('windowBounds', win.getBounds());
    })
    win.on('maximize', () => {
        store.set('isMaximized', true);
    })
    win.on('unmaximize', () => {
        store.set('isMaximized', false);
    })
    win.on('show', () => {
        win.setFullScreen(store.get('fullscreen'));
    })
    win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify();
    })
}

function createSettings() {
    settingScreen = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 600,
        height: 800,
        frame: false,
        parent: win,
        modal: true,
        titleBarStyle: "hidden",
        webPreferences: {
            enableRemoteModule: true,
            nodeIntegration: true,
            worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true
        },
        show: false
    })

    settingScreen.loadFile('extraWindows/settingsScreen/settings.html');

    settingScreen.on('close', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        settingScreen.hide();
    })
}


app.on('ready', () => {
    createLoadingScreen();

    setTimeout(() => {
        createWindow();
        createSettings();
    }, 5000); // Set to 5000
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if(process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
    if(BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
})

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    globalShortcut.register('CmdOrCtrl+O', () => {
        win.webContents.send('openFile');
    })
    globalShortcut.register('CmdOrCtrl+D', () => {
        win.webContents.send('closeFile');
    })
})

// These are all of the ipc functions needed for Route to work

ipcMain.handle('viewSettings', (event, arg) => {
    if(arg === "true") {
        settingScreen.show();
    } else if(arg === "false") {
        settingScreen.hide();
    }
});

ipcMain.handle('changeSettings', (event, arg) => {
    if(arg === "fullScreen") {
        if(win.isFullScreen() == false) {
            win.setFullScreen(true);
            store.set('fullscreen', true);
        } else {
            win.setFullScreen(false);
            store.set('fullscreen', false);
        }
        // Fill in the data for fullscreen
    } else if(arg === 'themechooser') {
        // Fill in the data for themes
    }
});

ipcMain.on('appVersion', (event) => {
    event.sender.send('appVersion', { version: app.getVersion() });
});

ipcMain.on('restartApp', () => {
    autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
})

autoUpdater.on('updateAvailable', () => {
    win.webContents.send('updateAvailable');
});

autoUpdater.on('updateDownloaded', () => {
    win.webContents.send('updateDownloaded');
})
```

And this is the renderer.js:

```js
const { app, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
const Store = require('./classes/Store.js');
const remote = require('electron').remote;
const dialog = require('electron').remote.dialog;
const fs = require('fs');
const { S_IFDIR } = require('constants');
const { electron } = require('process');
const { version } = require('os');

let currentWindow = remote.getCurrentWindow();
let $ = function(selector) {
    return document.querySelector(selector);
}

let projectArray = [];
// There can only be 5 projects max. Might add more.
let projectCount = 0;

document.querySelector('#tradeSetup').addEventListener('click', () => {
    //Create a new setup.
    alert("This works!");
});

let fileOpenerOptions = {
    title: "Open Trade File",
    defaultPath: "C:\\",
    buttonLabel: "Start Coding",
    properties: [ 'openFile' ],
    filters: [
        { name: 'Json', extensions: ['json'] },
        { name: 'All FIles', extensions: ['*'] }
    ]
}

//Top bar buttons
function openFile() {
    dialog.showOpenDialog(currentWindow, fileOpenerOptions).then(fileNames => {
        if(fileNames == undefined || fileNames == null) {
            console.log("No file selected.");
            return;
        } else {
            let projectName = path.basename(fileNames.filePaths[0], path.extname(fileNames.filePaths[0]));
            let rawFileData = fs.readFileSync(fileNames.filePaths[0]);
            let fileData = JSON.parse(rawFileData);
            console.log(fileData);
            if(projectCount < 5) {
                projectCount++;
                createProject(projectName, fileData);
                // Run code
            }  else if (projectCount == 5) {
                alert('Support for more projects is not available yet!\nPlease wait until a later update to have more than 5 projects.');
            }
        }
    });
}

function openSettings() {
    ipcRenderer.invoke('viewSettings', "true");
}

function closeFile() {
    if(document.querySelector('.activeProjectButton') == null) {
        console.log("No project to close.");
    } else {
        let contine = confirm("Is this project the furthest project to the right? If not, please don't close it.\nThis is a bug that is being worked on.");
        if(contine == true) {
            document.querySelector('.activeProjectButton').remove();
            document.querySelector('.activeWorkspace').remove();
            projectCount--;
            document.querySelectorAll('.inactiveProjectWorkspace').j--;
        }
        // Add a fun little secret for users
    }
}
 
document.querySelector('#openFile').addEventListener('click', () => {
    openFile();
});

document.querySelector('#openSettings').addEventListener('click', () => {
    openSettings();
});

document.querySelector('#closeFile').addEventListener('click', () => {
    closeFile();
})

// Create and switch projects
function createProject(name, projectData) {
    // This is a beta feature for now. It is not finished
    // Create the tab
    let projectInProduction = document.createElement("button");
    projectInProduction.id = "project" + projectCount + "Click";
    projectInProduction.classList.add("invisButton");
    projectInProduction.classList.add("inactiveProjectButton");
    projectInProduction.classList.add("project" + projectCount);
    projectInProduction.innerHTML += (name);

    // Remove the welcome message
    document.querySelector('.unHidden').classList.add('hidden');
    document.querySelector('.unHidden').classList.remove('unHidden');

    //Create the workspace
    let workspaceInProduction = document.createElement("div");
    workspaceInProduction.classList.add("inactiveWorkspace");
    projectArray.push(projectData);
    if(projectArray[projectCount - 1].tiers == null) {
        alert("This is not a trade file!\nPlease use a trade file!");
    } else {
        $('.projects').appendChild(projectInProduction);
        $('#jsonProjectContainer').appendChild(workspaceInProduction);
        let table = document.createElement('table');
        table.innerHTML += '<tr><th colspan="3">Buying</th><th colspan="2">Selling</th></tr>';
        table.classList.add('table' + projectCount);
        workspaceInProduction.appendChild(table);
        let tiers = Object.keys(projectArray[projectCount - 1].tiers).length;
        console.log(tiers);
        for(let i = 0; i < tiers; i++) {
            let tradesC = Object.keys(projectArray[projectCount - 1].tiers[i].trades).length;
            for(let j = 0; j < tradesC; j++) {
                let wants = Object.keys(projectArray[projectCount - 1].tiers[i].trades[j].wants);
                let wantsC = Object.keys(projectArray[projectCount - 1].tiers[i].trades[j].wants).length;
                let gives = Object.keys(projectArray[projectCount - 1].tiers[i].trades[j].gives);
                for(let k = 0; k < wantsC; k++) {
                    let wantsItem = projectArray[projectCount - 1].tiers[i].trades[j].wants[k].item;
                    let wantsMin = projectArray[projectCount - 1].tiers[i].trades[j].wants[k].quantity["min"];
                    let wantsMax = projectArray[projectCount - 1].tiers[i].trades[j].wants[k].quantity["max"];
                    let givesItem = projectArray[projectCount - 1].tiers[i].trades[j].gives[0].item;
                    console.log("Wants: " + wants[k]);
                    console.log("Min: " + wantsMin);
                    console.log("Max: " + wantsMax);
                    console.log("Item: " + wantsItem);
                    console.log("Gives: " + gives);
                    console.log("Item: " + givesItem);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    // Add a onlclick function to make switching projects work
    j = projectCount;
    document.getElementById('project' + projectCount + 'Click').addEventListener('click', function(j) {
        let buttonIndex = j;
        let buttonNodes = $('.projects').children;
        let workspaceNodes = $('#jsonProjectContainer').children;
        for(let i = 0; i < buttonNodes.length; i++) {
            if(i == (j - 1)) {
                buttonNodes[i].classList.add('activeProjectButton');
                buttonNodes[i].classList.remove('inactiveProjectButton');
                workspaceNodes[i].classList.add('activeWorkspace');
                workspaceNodes[i].classList.remove('inactiveWorkspace');
            } else {
                buttonNodes[i].classList.remove('activeProjectButton');
                buttonNodes[i].classList.add('inactiveProjectButton');
                workspaceNodes[i].classList.remove('activeWorkspace');
                workspaceNodes[i].classList.add('inactiveWorkspace');
            }
        }
    }.bind(null, j));
}

// Title bar scripts
ipcRenderer.on('openFile', () => {
    openFile();
})
ipcRenderer.on('closeFile', () => {
    closeFile();
})

// App updates
ipcRenderer.send('appVersion');
ipcRenderer.on('appVersion', (event, arg) => {
    ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('appVersion');
    //version.innerText = ;
});

const updateNotifier = document.getElementById('updateNotifier');
const updateAvailability = document.getElementById('updateAvailability');
const restartButton = document.getElementById('restartButton');

ipcRenderer.on('updateAvailable', () => {
    ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('updateAvailable');
    updateAvailability.innerText = 'A new version of Route is available. Downloading now...';
    updateNotifier.classList.remove('hidden');
});

ipcRenderer.on('update_downloaded', () => {
    ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('updateDownloaded');
    updateAvailability.innerText = 'Update downloaded. It will be installed on restart. Restart to continue.';
    restartButton.classList.remove('hidden');
    updateNotifier.classList.remove('hidden');
});
function restartApp() {
    ipcRenderer.send('restartApp');
}
```

And this is the index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>route - Minecraft Addon Tool</title>
        <!-- https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#csp-meta-tag -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
        <link href="index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="node_modules/@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            // const electron = require('electron').remote;
            const path = require('path');
            const customTitleBar = require('custom-electron-titlebar');
            const Menu = require('electron').remote.Menu;
            const MenuItem = require('electron').remote.MenuItem;

            let mainTitlebar = new customTitleBar.Titlebar({
                backgroundColor: customTitleBar.Color.fromHex('#391B47'),
                icon: 'build/icons/icon.png'
            });

            const menu = new Menu();
            menu.append(new MenuItem({
                label: 'Github',
                click: () => {
                    currentWindow.webContents.on('new-window', require('electron').shell.openExternal('https://github.com/Gekocaretaker/route'));
                }
            }));
            menu.append(new MenuItem({
                label: 'Discord',
                click: () => {
                    console.log("Hiding the link!");
                }
            }));
            menu.append(new MenuItem({
                label: 'File',
                submenu: [
                    {
                        label: 'Open File',
                        accelerator: 'Ctrl+O',
                        click: () => {
                            openFile();
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Close File',
                        accelerator: 'Ctrl+D',
                        click: () => {
                            closeFile();
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'New File',
                        accelerator: 'Ctrl+N',
                        click: () => {
                            console.log("This is not yet available.");
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }))

            mainTitlebar.updateMenu(menu);
        </script>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="buttons">
                <div class="tooltip openFileContainer">
                    <button id="openFile" class="invisButton"><span class="mdi mdi-file mdi-48px"></span></button>
                    <div>File</div>
                </div>
                <div class="tooltip settingsContainer">
                    <button id="openSettings" class="invisButton"><span class="mdi mdi-cog-outline mdi-48px"></span></button>
                    <div>Settings</div>
                </div>
                <div class="tooltip closeProjectContainer">
                    <button id="closeFile" class="invisButton"><span class="mdi mdi-close mdi-48px"></span></button>
                    <div>Close Project</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="projects">
                <!-- <div class="project1">
                    <button class="invisButton activeProjectButton" id="project1Click">Project 1</button>
                </div> -->
            </div>
            <div class="jsonEditor">
                <!-- <div class="workSpace1 activeWorkSpace">
                    <h3>This is Workspace 1</h3>
                </div> -->
                <div id="jsonProjectContainer"></div>
                <div class="unHidden">
                    <p id="welcomeMessage">Hello User! Welcome to Route. I hope you enjoy using this!</p>
                </div>
                <div id="updateNotifier" class="hidden">
                    <p id="updateAvailability"></p>
                    <button id="restartButton" onclick="restartApp()"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
                <div class="tooltip tradeBuilder">
                    <button id="tradeSetup" class="invisButton"><span class="mdi mdi-apache-kafka mdi-48px"></span></button>
                    <div>Basic Trade</div>
                </div>
                <div class="tooltip whatNext">
                    <button id="whatsNext" class="invisButton"><span class="mdi mdi-help mdi-48px"></span></button>
                    <div>Whats Next?</div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <script src="renderer.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'min' of undefined
> at createProject (renderer.js:126)
> at renderer.js:48

And I am pretty sure the error comes from how I get "min". I have tried using ["min"], ['min'], .min, and as a last resort, [0].

I have the code hosted on github, if needing to be shared.

Comment: *"I am pretty sure..."*: If you read the error message again, you'll notice "...of undefined". This does not say something about `min`, but about the entity that you think has the property `min`. The message is saying that this entity is not an object, but is undefined. In other words, the problem is with `quantity`: that property is undefined in `wants[0]`.

Comment: @trincot Could you clarify how I would get it to work? I don't understand how `quantity` could be undefined in `wants` when it is there in the file. Do you know how I could get quantity correctly?

Comment: Your question should include the code to reproduce the problem. Currently, the code does not match with the JSON: that latter is not an array, and you address it as one (`projectArray`). Your code includes variables that are not defined (`projectArray`, `projectCount`, `wants`, `k`, `gives`...). If you want help, make sure the question has all (but not more) what is needed to reproduce the error.

Comment: The json file data is put into an array for easier management, and I forgot to change `k` to a `0` because it is used in a for loop because there is more data, I just condensed it to make it easier to read.

Comment: I can only repeat: If you want help, make sure the question has all (but not more) what is needed to reproduce the error. (use the edit link)

Comment: @trincot Here is the link with the entire project: https://github.com/Gekocaretaker/route

Comment: @trincot I updated the question to have the 4 files. I left out one js file called Store.js which is just used for saving settings for the user. I can add it if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would debug your code, you would notice that the error occurs when j=1 and k=0. Then if you check the object, you notice that at that location there is no `question` property:

```
{
  "tiers": [
    {
      "trades": [
        {
            /* ... */
        },
        {
          "wants": [
            {
              "item": "minecraft:emerald"
              /* no quantity here */
            }
          ],
          "gives": [
              /* ... */
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    /* ... */
```

So you'll have to decide what you want to happen when there is no `quantity` property. You can for instance use the optional chaining operator to use a default value:

```
let wantsMin = projectArray[projectCount - 1].tiers[i].trades[j].wants[k].quantity.?min || 0;
let wantsMax = projectArray[projectCount - 1].tiers[i].trades[j].wants[k].quantity.?max || 0;
```

The above would give 0 as value for the min/max values that are missing. But all depends on what you want to happen in this scenario.

This is just an example on how you can circumvent the error, but might not be the right way to deal with it in light of the rest of your code. That is up to you to determine.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me a lot.

Answer (score -2):

This code is to access or process the values that are in nested array.we are iterating with loops and checks the iterating values that either it is an array or not with .isArray if yes we fetch the value ,if no we return the value.

```js
var arr=[['hi'],
         ['hello',['welcome','bye']],
        ['world']];
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
    for(var j=0; j<arr.length; j++)
    {
       if(Array.isArray(arr[i][j]))
       {
           for(var k=0; k<arr.length; k++)
           {
               console.log(arr[i][j][k]);
           }
       }
       else
       {
           console.log(arr[i][j]);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding code snippets is good. But also consider adding an explanation to your answer. @Harsh

Comment: @R.K
Thanks for your valuable suggestion ,I will implement it